# How do I declare an array of pointers-to-integer dynamically in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why does this work?

```
int **ar1 = new int*[5];
```

while this throws an error in c++:

```
int *ar2[] = new int*[5];
```

I understand that in the first case ar1 represents a pointer-to-pointer while in the second case ar2 represents an array of pointer-to-integer. Given the fact that the line "new int*[5]" means that the new operator is returning the pointer to memory space to store 5 pointers to integers, what is the problem with the second case???

Comment: Or you could simply use a `std::vector` and forget all about this _pointer / C arrays / new[]_ shebang.

Comment: You'll make your life a whole lot easier if you `typedef`/`using` `int*`. If this is just for learning purposes, of course go ahead. But for production code, please don't try to manage your own dynamic arrays, it's far too easy to mess up. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: It's the same problem as if you write `int ar[] = new int[5];`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to [initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) an array object.

> When initializing an object of array type, the initializer must be
>   either a **string literal** (optionally enclosed in braces) or be a
>   **brace-enclosed list** of initialized for array members:

In your case you provide neither. Brace initialization for example:

```
int i = 1, j = 2;
int *ar2[] = {&i, &j};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first try to simplify the question

This question is not correlated to **pointer to integers**, your problem is with the arrays itself.

So, try to simplify it to just an array of integers

This works

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

While this doesn't work

```
int a[] = new int[7];
```

And it fails with the following error

> error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘a’

When tried it on an online compiler that generates the assembly (tried on clang 6.0.0), it is found that

```
int a[]
```

is tried to be allocated on the **stack**, which means that size should be known at compile time, while the result of a `new` operator is not known until runtime, because it dynamically allocates the array on the **heap** {a lot of calculations via a system call is what decide the place of the array in memory}.

For more information about stack vs heap:

[Stack and heap](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)

**NOTE:** When there is a `[]` parameter in a function, it is just like `*`

So

```
void doSomething(int b[]) {
}

int main() {
    doSomething(new int[100])
    return 0;
}
```

is valid

The problem is mainly about local variables.

Anyway, if you are trying to make some production code, you are advised to use `shared_ptr`, `vector` and other C++ features,  you are not doing C programming.